# Intermediate value theorem for functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\subset \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on $(a,b)$, such that $f´(t)\neq 0 $ for all $t\in(a,b)$.
   Prove that there exists $\xi \in (a,b) $ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that:

$$f(b)-f(a)= \lambda f´(\xi)$$

What I have so far is that by applying the one dimensional case, i get that:
$$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)(f_1´(\xi_1), f_2´(\xi_2))$$
For some $\xi_1,\ \xi_2 \in \mathbb R$. Thus one way to prove it would be by showing that $\xi_1=\xi_2$, and this is where I´ve no clue how to proceed.

Comment: It's a pretty immediate consequence of the extended mean value theorem, aka the Cauchy mean value theorem, if applied to the two components of $f$.

Comment: just a guess, but try the Cauchy mean value theorem, because the regular mean value theorem, as you said, causes issues with the two different points $\xi_1, \xi_2$

Comment: For Cauchy's MVT see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Hint: apply the mean value theorem to the function $h(t) = v\cdot f(t) $, where $v$ is a vector orthogonal to $f(b) - f(a) $, $\cdot$ is the inner product.

Comment: @zhoraster You should give an official answer.